# Como verificar objetos en un ciclo en java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

queria saber si es posible hacer una validacion, por poner un ejemplo, si tengo 3 jtextfield con nombre en serie ejm:
jTextField1
jTextField2
jTextField3
(obviamente mas)
y quiero ver que tienen almacenado, lo puedo hacer en un ciclo? y en el caso de que si, como lo podria hacer?

Comment: [edit] tu pregunta con el código que tengas, así la comunidad estará mas dispuesta a ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La única forma en que puedes iterar sobre variables (campos) nombrados en forma parecida es usar *reflection* con el método `class.getDeclaredField(String name)`.

Uso de *reflection* generalmente es lento, entonces sería más recomendable de guardar tus variables en un arreglo o una lista para empezar:

```
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
textFields.add(new JTextField());
// luego se puede usar un iterator para recorrer los jTextField
Iterator<JTextField> it = textFields.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
    JTextField tf = it.next();
    // lo que quieres hacer con tf...
}
```

Comment: Gracias, es lo que buscaba <3